# show and hide divs based on radio button click

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I want to be able to dynamically change what divs are show using radio button and jQuery  -  HTML:

```
  <div id="myRadioGroup">

2 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" checked="checked" value="2"  />

3 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" value="3" />

<div id="twoCarDiv">
2 Cars Selected
</div>
<div id="threeCarDiv">
3 Cars
</div>
</div>
```

and the jQuery:

```
     <script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name$='cars']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#"+test).show();
    }); 
});
</script>
```

This does nothing , the divs always show. Im sure this is simple, but Im poor at jQuery .

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you forgot two things:

1. add the `desc` classes to your description divs
2. You have numeric values for the `input` but text for the `id`.

I have fixed the above and also added a line to initially `hide()` the *third* description div.

Check it out in action - http://jsfiddle.net/VgAgu/3/

#### HTML

```
<div id="myRadioGroup">
    2 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" checked="checked" value="2"  />
    3 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" value="3" />

    <div id="Cars2" class="desc">
        2 Cars Selected
    </div>
    <div id="Cars3" class="desc" style="display: none;">
        3 Cars
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='cars']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#Cars" + test).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Man, in my case, it will show some required input to fill based on the selected radio button. my question is how to NOT required the hidden inputs?

Comment: this not working if you select other radio option other than default checked and reload the page.

Comment: Avoid hiding an element with inline styling defaulting to display:none as this will cause issues. It's better to use a css class to override the default display so that you don't have to override the specificity with !important attributes later on.

Answer (score 12):

You were pretty close. You're description `div` tags didn't have the `.desc` class defined. For your scenario you should have the radio button value equal to the `div` that you're trying to show.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myRadioGroup">

    2 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" checked="checked" value="twoCarDiv"  />

    3 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" value="threeCarDiv" />

    <div id="twoCarDiv" class="desc">
        2 Cars Selected
    </div>
    <div id="threeCarDiv" class="desc">
        3 Cars Selected
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("input[name$='cars']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#" + test).show();
    });
});
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/tcDtr/

Comment: This is very helpful tips. Thank you for this nice solution.

Comment: This still doesn't show the div on page load where the input is `checked`. Only the radio is shown as selected.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function show(str){
                document.getElementById('sh2').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('sh1').style.display = 'block';
            }
            function show2(sign){
                document.getElementById('sh2').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('sh1').style.display = 'none';
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="r1" id="e1" onchange="show2()"/>&nbsp;I Am New User&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="r1" onchange="show(this.value)"/>&nbsp;Existing Member
        </p>
        <div id="sh1">Hello There !!</div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div id="sh2" style="display:none;">Hey Watz up !!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find exactly what you are looking for.

```
<div align="center">
  <input type="radio" name="name_radio1" id="id_radio1" value="value_radio1">Radio1
  <input type="radio" name="name_radio1″ id="id_radio2" value="value_radio2″>Radio2
</div>
 <br />
<div align="center" id="id_data" style="border:5″>
  <div>this is div 1</div>
  <div>this is div 2</div>
  <div>this is div 3</div>
  <div>this is div 4</div>
</div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 // show the table as soon as the DOM is ready
 $("#id_data").show();
 // shows the table on clicking the noted link
  $("#id_radio1").click(function() {
   $("#id_data").show("slow");
  });
 // hides the table on clicking the noted link
   $("#id_radio2").click(function() {
   $("#id_data").hide("fast");
   });
 });
```

```
  $(document).ready(function(){} – When document load.
  $("#id_data").show(); – shows div which contain id #id_data.
  $("#id_radio1").click(function() – Checks  radio button is clicked containing id #id_radio1.
  $("#id_data").show("slow"); – shows div containing id #id_data.
  $("#id_data").hide("fast"); -hides div when click on radio button containing id #id_data.
```

Thats it..

http://patelmilap.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/show-hide-div-on-click-using-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you need

http://jsfiddle.net/7Ud6B/

Answer (score 1):

The hide selector was incorrect. I hid the blocks at page load and showed the selected value. I also changed the car div id's to make it easier to append the radio button value and create the proper id selector.

```
<div id="myRadioGroup">
  2 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" checked="checked" value="2"  />
  3 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" value="3" />
  <div id="car-2">
  2 Cars
  </div>
  <div id="car-3">
  3 Cars
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("div div").hide();
  $("#car-2").show();
  $("input[name$='cars']").click(function() {
      var test = $(this).val();
      $("div div").hide();
      $("#car-"+test).show();
  }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `$("div.desc").hide();` you are essentially trying to hide a div with a class name of `desc`. Which doesn't exist. With `$("#"+test).show();` you are trying to show either a div with an id of `#2` or `#3`. Those are illegal id's in HTML (can't start with a number), though they will work in many browsers. However, they don't exist.

I'd rename the two divs to `carDiv2` and `carDiv3` and then use different logic to hide or show.

```
if((test) == 2) { ... }
```

Also, use a class for your checkboxes so your binding becomes something like

```
$('.carCheckboxes').click(function ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector for the `.show()` and `.hide()` are not pointing to anything in the code.

[Fixed version in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaneblake/UQgvc/)