# show and hide divs based on radio button click

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have checked [show and hide divs based on radio button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940963/jquery-show-and-hide-divs-based-on-radio-button-click), but my code still doesn't work. Basically the div tag will be hidden unless click the "package_1"

```
    HTML is like this:
   <table><tr><td>
    <input type="radio" name="cars" id="Package_1"  />
    <input type="radio" name="cars" id="Package_2"/> 
   </td></tr></table>   
    <div class="package_extension"></div>  

   JQuery below:  

    $(".package_extension").hide();
    $("#Package_1").click(function(){
       $(".package_extension").show();
      });
```

Comment: You are missing quotes.

Comment: This might help [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tXUGF/)

Comment: Your JavaScript might need to be wrapped in a DOM ready event.

Comment: Yes,it is in the DOM right now. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why this one is closed. The question is relevant for a large group and the answers given are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

your jquery should be like this, you've missed the quote and also wrong placement of parenthesis

```
 $(".package_extension").hide();
 $("#Package_1").click(function(){
     $(".package_extension").show();
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for editing, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: did you placed the javascript code inside the script tag ?

Comment: Yes. It works know, I forgot to type a ;....Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes

```
$('.package_extension').hide();
 $('#Package_1').click(function(){
 $('.package_extension').show();

 )};
```

try this.

Comment: It doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/46/

```
<table><tr><td>
    <input type="radio" name="cars" id="Package_1"  />
    <input type="radio" name="cars" id="Package_2"/> 
   </td></tr></table>   
    <div class="package_extension"> package_extension </div>  

$(".package_extension").hide();
     $("#Package_1").click(function(){
         $(".package_extension").show();
     });
```